# Use @MappedSuperclass association mapping with generics in springboot jpa

Tags: spring-boot, database-design, spring-data-jpa, entity

I have a bunch of entites that follow the same pattern of parent <-> children relationship and I want to use @MappedSuperclass with generics to abstract such relationship.

I have read a bunch of existing posts about generics in JPA but seems like none of them fits my case.

Here is my super class:

```java
@MappedSuperclass
public abstract class BaseEntity<T extends BaseEntity, U extends BaseEntity> {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private int id;
    private String name;
    private Timestamp createdAt;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "parentId")
    private T parent;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "parent")
    private Set<U> children;
    // getters and setters
}
```

The example implenmentation would be.

```java
@Entity
public class Country extends BaseEntity<Country, State> 

@Entity
public class State extends BaseEntity<Country, City> 

@Entity
public class City extends BaseEntity<State, Neighbourhood> 

@Entity
public class Neighbourhood extends BaseEntity<City,Neighbourhood>
```

The entityManager declares error
And the entity manager decalres
`org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'entityManagerFactory' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/orm/jpa/HibernateJpaConfiguration.class]:`